# i use many to many relationship but it not save data in through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have 2 model book and wishlist.
and between this 2 model i use many to many relationship.

Below is my model.

```
  class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :book_wishlist_customizations, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :wish_lists ,through: :book_wishlist_customizations

  end

 class BookWishlistCustomization < ActiveRecord::Base  # through table
   belongs_to :wish_list
   belongs_to :book
 end

 class WishList < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :book_wishlist_customizations
   has_many :books,through: :book_wishlist_customizations
 end
```

when i delete book from admin side it raise following error.

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "books" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_7a6b92667b" on table "wish_lists" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "wish_lists". : DELETE FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" = $1.
```

below is my book form.

```
  <%= form_for @book, url: books_path do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :stream_id %>
        <%= f.collection_select :stream_id, Stream.all, :id, :stream_name, prompt: true %>
      </div> 

      </br>
      <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :university_board_id, "University" %>
        <%= f.collection_select :university_board_id, UniversityBoard.where(category_id: $college_id).all, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
      </div>

      </br>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :course_standard_id, "Course & Year" %>
        <%=f.select(:course_standard_id, :"Please select" => true)%>
        <%=f.select(:year_semester, :"Please select" => true)%>
      </div>

      </br>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :college_school_id, "College" %>
         <%=f.select(:college_school_id, :"Please select" => true)%>
      </div>

      </br>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :subject_id, "Subject" %>
        <%=f.select(:subject_id, :"Please select" => true)%>
      </div>

      </br>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :book_name, "Book name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :book_name %>
      </div>

      </br>
      <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Continue", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

below is my controller:-

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @book = Book.new
       $college_id = Category.where(category_name: ['college']).select(:id)
       $school_id = Category.where(category_name: ['school']).select(:id)
    end

    def create  
       if user_signed_in?
          @book = Book.new(book_params)
          @last_commision = Commision.last
          @book_status = BookStatus.find_by(status_name: "pending")
          @book.update_attributes( commision_id: @last_commision.id, book_status_id: @book_status.id, user_id: current_user.id, quantity: "1")
          if @book.save
             # exit
             session[:book_id] = @book.id
             # session[:photo_id] = @book_photo.id
             redirect_to multi_steps_path
          else
             respond_to do |format|
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
       else
          session[:book_details] = book_params
          redirect_to unauthenticated_root_path, notice: "For post your book first login in our system."
       end
   end

   def stream_change_course
       @stream_details=CourseStandard.where(stream_id: params[:stream], category_id: $college_id)
       render :json => @stream_details
   end

   def course_change_college_subject
       @year_semester=CourseStandard.where(id: params[:course])
       @subject_details=Subject.where(course_standard_id: CourseStandard.where(category_id: $college_id))
       @college_details=CollegeSchool.where(course_standard_id: CourseStandard.where(category_id: $college_id))
       render :json => {:subject => @subject_details,:college => @college_details,:year =>@year_semester}
   end

   def price_calculate_commission
       @final_amount=params[:price].to_i-(params[:price].to_i*Commision.last.percentage)/100
       render :json => @final_amount
   end

private
    def book_params
       params.require(:book).permit(:book_id, :user_id, :book_name, :book_condition_id,:price_for_sale, :mrp, :book_auther, :isbn, :description, :publish_year, :edition, :publication, :book_status_id, :quantity, :category_id, :university_board_id, :college_school_id, :course_standard_id, :subject_id, :commision_id, :stream_id, :medium_id,:year_semester) rescue {}
       # params.require(:book).permit(:stream_id, :university_board_id, :course_standard_id, :subject_id, :id)
    end
    def book_photo_params
      params.require(:book_photo).permit(:photo) rescue {}
    end
end
```

Comment: you are getting error on delete because There is still a record referencing to id `1`. You have to delete all records in `wish_list` referencing to id `1` in `book`. If not, the db protects you from doing harm to the data.

Comment: @Sontya when i delete book than it also have to delete from the wishlist, because i give dependent:destroy

Comment: when i manually add entry in through table than it successfully delete book

Comment: Where is the code where you try to delete the book? What command do you use?

Comment: @Albin i delete record using activeadmin

Comment: I think you should use `destroy`. `delete` does not trigger callbacks and then `dependent: :destroy` does not matter.

Comment: Yes ashvin,where is your destroy method. Let us see that

Comment: I told you above that i am using activeadmin(in activeadmin not require to write delete or destroy method)

Comment: Then I think you will need to start by deleting all `book_wishlist_customizations ` that is connected to a book and then delete that book.

Comment: but i put the relationship on book to whislist so it automatically deleted because of dependency destroy

Comment: No it is NOT automatically deleted since the method you seem to be running is delete not destroy. And that is what is triggering your error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from your error that your WishList model has a field for book ids. It shouldn't. Your BookWishListCustomization model's book id field and wishlist id field along with the belongs_to and has_many associations your models have now are enough.